# 2 approximation for minimization problems

Tags: algorithm, approximation

I have a general question, I know there is a way to find 2-approximation for maximization problems by finding 2 solution `s1` and `s2` s.t

```
q(s1)+q(s2)>=q(OPT)
```

and by chosing `max{q(s1),q(s2)}` i've found a legit approx.

Back to my question,
Is it possible to do this general method for minimization problems ? 
What will be the analog?

Comment: That does not make much sense to me (in the general-case). Would you add some context please? As edge-coloring can be formulated as maximization-problem and it's not APX-complete, there is no such constant-factor approximation. Doesn't that contradict your initial statement?

Comment: for example, You can find 2-approx for the Knapsack problem when you sort by the Specific value and if k is the last item that by picking him youll overflow the knapsack, you can choose between the 1,2,...,k-1 items or the k item as a final answer and you'll get 2-approx

Comment: **But that's not general**. It's limited to this specific problem!

Comment: It isnt specific for maximization  problems

Comment: But why, isnt the max value of two soultions that there sum is bigger than the optimal soultion will raise at least half of opt ?

Comment: @sascha Ok you are right, if i'll change it to general in a sense that the optinal solution is a number, that will be correct ?

Comment: I still don't know what you want to express here. It's way to informal and i'm afraid that won't change that fast. Nonetheless, [this probably answers your question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/48776/converting-maximization-to-minimization-in-aproximation-algorithms).

Comment: Thanks, That is what i meant